# problem getting data from api as Future inside build() method in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, asynchronous, future

My problem is with Futures, because they should be obtained before build() method executed, as the documentation states:

> The future must be obtained earlier, because if the future is created
> at the same time as the FutureBuilder, then every time the
> FutureBuilder's parent is rebuilt, the asynchronous task will be
> restarted.

I know that Futures should be called in initstate() function before the build method executed, but my case is different.

I want to get data from api as a Future, but the request I am sending to the api needs some parameters that user should select inside the screen's build() method.

And I don't know what the parameter of the request will be until user selects in build() method, and I have to call the api in the build() method and use FutureBuilder there, but that makes FutureBuilder to get constantly called, and I don't want that.

basically, I don't want to call FutureBuilder indefinetely, and I can't put my Future inside initState() because the Future needs some parameters that user later selects when the screen is shown inside build() method.

inside the build method:

```
FutureBuilder<List<LatLng>>(
                        builder: (context, snapshot) {
                          if (snapshot.hasData) {
                            return PolylineLayer(
                              polylines: [
                                Polyline(
                                    points: snapshot.data!,
                                    strokeWidth: 4,
                                    color: Colors.purple),
                              ],
                            );
                          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                            return Text("${snapshot.error}");
                          } else {
                            return Container();
                          }
                        },
                        future: Provider.of<NavigationProvider>(context)
                            .getNavigationPoints(pointToGoTo!),
                      ),
```

now if you look at the code, at the final lines, I am sending the parameter pointToGoTo to the function which calls the backend.

simply, I want to get rid of calling api and getting data back as a Future inside build method, I want to do it in initState or somewhere else that prevents the build methods calling backend indefinitely.

is there any way to fix this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: *Futures should be called in initstate()* not necessarily, you can create a state variable and make it nullable, while placing assigning the variable call  show the FutureBuilder

Comment: can you include you code?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh

creating a state variable does not solve my problem, because when I create the variable, in the build method I can assign the variable, but also in build() method I should call the api request, so anytime the build() method rebuilds, a request for backend will be sent and future builder will be called indefinitely.

Comment: FutureBuilder doesnt calls api only once, unless you call method directly inside build method.

Comment: @eamirho3ein 

I updated the question now, you can see the code.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh

can you look at the question again please, I have updated the question and provided code this time.

Comment: You are getting api call on every build because of `future: Provider.of<NavigationProvider(context).getNavigationPoints(pointToGoTo!),` create a state variable and check the  Randal L. Schwartz's video the one I've attached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, create future state variable and  a nullable params and use it  with conditional if while using FutureBuilder.

I will recommend checking [Fixing a common FutureBuilder and StreamBuilder problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqE-J8YJnpg)

Now you can follow this example. It is missing progressBar on API recall, StreamBuilder might be better option in cases like this.

```dart
class Foo extends StatefulWidget {
  const Foo({super.key});

  @override
  State<Foo> createState() => _FooState();
}

class _FooState extends State<Foo> {
  int? params;

  Future<int> fetch(int? data) async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
    return (params ?? 0) * 2;
  }

  late Future<int> future = fetch(params);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          DropdownButton<int?>(
            value: params,
            items: List.generate(
                12,
                (index) => DropdownMenuItem(
                      value: index,
                      child: Text("$index"),
                    )).toList(),
            onChanged: (value) {
              future =
                  fetch(params); // this will only call api with update data
              setState(() {
                params = value;
              });
            },
          ),
          if (params != null)
            FutureBuilder<int>(
              future: future,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) return Text("${snapshot.data}");
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              },
            )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You can also make nullable future and do check as  before FutureBuilder,  `late Future<int>? future`

Answer (score 1):

```
class Testing extends StatefulWidget {
  const Testing({super.key});

  @override
  State<Testing> createState() => _TestingState();
}

class _TestingState extends State<Testing> {

bool isFetched = false;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Consumer<SomethingProvider>(
      builder: (context, prov, child) {
        if (!isFetched) {
          prov.getData("a", "b");
          Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 200), () {
            isFetched = true;
          });
        }
        if (prov.newData.isNotEmpty) {
          return Column(
              // make widget tree from here
              );
        } else {
          return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }
      },
    ),
  );
 }
}

class SomethingProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  List newData = [];

  Future getData(param1, param2) async {
    newData = ["testingdata"];
  }
}
```